# Trying to open image with pysimplegui, but getting error window pop up

Tags: python, image, pysimplegui

I am following this tutorial to try and get an image to show up in a window with pysimplegui. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KtlGrgWf6Y8

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import os

layout = [
            [sg.Image(filename='test_image_2.png')],
            [sg.Button('Exit')]
        ]

window = sg.Window("Image Viewer", layout)

while True:
        event, values = window.read()
        if event == "Exit" or event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
            break

window.close()
```

I use the same code that the teacher uses, and the same image file and saved in the same folder as the python file.
When i run the code, I get the following window pop up:
[error pop up window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dd6DM.png)

I cannot understand why this would be showing. Do i need to save the image file to a different location? Or is it something else?

Comment: Well, as the error message indicates, there is no file called 'test_image_2.png' in your working directory. Make sure, the file is located in the same folder where you python scripts runs in

Comment: Thank you for your response! Perhaps this is my issue. My image is in the same folder as the python code. Is this folder the "working directory" you are referring to, or something else? Is there a difference between where the python code is saved, and where the python scripts run in?

Comment: The working directory is from where you are running your python script. Example: if your script is in `/home/user/script.py` and you run your script from `/home` (`python3 user/script.py`), your working directory is `/home`. You get get your working directory by importing os (`import os`) and then use `os.getcwd()`.

Comment: Perhaps use the full pathname to start and work backwards from there?  (i.e. get it to work and then mess around with relative paths).  If your image is in the same folder as your application, consider using `r'./test_image_2.png'` for the filename.